# Non-inverting Integrator

Tags: operational-amplifier, pspice, integrator

I am trying to design a non-inverting integrator to get a triangular wave from a square wave. (the square wave will be generated using a 555 timer)

I am using this design i found online: FIG1

I calculated its transfer function and i got: H(s)= 1/(R*C*s)

When I try to simulate the circuit (FIG2) using PSpice I get this output: FIG3

With the vaalues I used shouldn't I have to be getting a higer amplitude signal??
Is there something wrong with the desing/calculations??
Thanks a lot in advanced and sorry for my bad english :-/

** Since i cannot post more than one link there are all the pictures in a big one:
[image]

Comment: Check the GBW product and slewrate of the LM324. It really wasn't designed for 4us period signals...

Comment: Thanks @BrianDrummond, i did not take in account the slew rate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LM324 output can drive maybe 10mA - you will have to increase those 10 ohm resistors significantly.

Try reducing the input frequency to maybe 1kHz and use 2.5K/1n or 25k/100pF.

As @packt notes your inverting/non-inverting inputs appear to be swapped in the Orcad or PSPICE schematic.

You are not going to get any kind of acceptable results at 250kHz using an op-amp such as the LM324 with a typical slew rate of 400mV/us - for a 3V output it would have to slew 3000mV in 2us which is 1500mV/us. It just cannae do it, even disregarding the input error magnitude.

In fact if you just connect the op-amp as a voltage follower you should get a triangle wave output, getting the same crappy results with far fewer parts.

---

Edit: here is what I mean (in the comments) by incorporating an integrator into the 555 oscillator. The inverter should be a CMOS buffer such as the single gate buffer with high drive capability (eg. 32mA). The op-amp needs to be reasonably fast. Increase R3 and/or C1 to get lower frequency- this value is roughly your initial 250kHz frequency.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqpXjd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a conventional inverting integrator driven by the difference between the 2.5V voltage at the R1/R2 voltage divider and the buffer output. When the 555 output is high, the inverter output is close to GND and the integrator output ramps up until it reaches 3.33V. Then the 555 output goes low, the buffer output goes very close to 5V and the integrator output ramps down until it reaches 1.67V and the cycle repeats.

Comment: Hi @spheropefhany, thanks a lot for your quick response.

Comment: I did not take in account the slew rate of the op amp and I can see that is a problem.

My problem is that i need to generate a triangular wave with a frequency of arround 100kHz. Using a 555 to generate a square wave and then integrate it was my first thougght but clearly its not going to work (at least the integration part).
Any ideas on how to get that 100kHz triangular wave?
Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Well the 555 generates a reasonably triangular wave too, you just have to pick it off another pin - unless you need a perfectly triangular wave.

Comment: That's the problem,  I need a perfect (or as good as possible)  triangular wave.  This is because the triangular wave would be used as reference for a comparator in a Class D amplifier.  Any suggestions on how to get that triangular wave? Thanks again

Comment: As @Brian says if you pick off the capacitor voltage and buffer it, it is sort-of triangular and goes from 1/3 to 2/3 Vcc. Another approach is to use the integrator as part of the oscillator, which could give you nice triangle waves. In any case you'll need a much faster op-amp.

Comment: Hi @SpehroPefhany im not sure about what you mean  when saying "use the integrator as part of the oscillator"

Comment: Any ideas guys?  :-)

Comment: Thank you @SpehroPefhany, you solved my problem. I think I will use your design.
Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

That's **not** a non-inverting integrator you have there but an oscillator, because your feedback is positive.

You have to put another OP as an inverter stage behind the first stage, or put a second, identical RC combination at the input. See http://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/261247/integrierer.png

Comment: Of course, it is an integrator. Its name is "BTC integrator" (BTC: Balanced Time Constants). It is not true that positive feedback causes oscillation. However, the invers is true: Oscillators always have positive feedback.

Comment: correction: It is not true that positive feedback ALWAYS causes oscillation.

Comment: Hi @janka thanks for your quick answer. I swaped the inverting and non inverting inputs but the problem persists.

Also, what software are you using in your simulation?

Thanks

Comment: @LvW: I never stated something like "positive feedback ALWAYS causes oscillation". Positive feedback causes self-amplification of the signal. When you have only resistors in the positive feedback path, it gives you a Schmitt trigger. When you have C or L in the positive feedback path, it gives you to a relaxation oscillator. The BTC integrator you mentioned has feedback to the **inverting input**. It's the circuit I proposed (see the link) as an alternative to putting an inverter OP behind the first stage OP.

Comment: Janka, sorry you are right. I just saw the (rather small) circuit diagram - very similar to the BTC intergator, but I did not recognize the "+" and "-" signs at the input. That means: I automatically did assume the correct polarity (which, in fact, was wrong). However, changing the polarity it is - in fact- a positive integrator (for equal time constants).

Comment: It happened to me, too. Then I looked at the plot and double-checked.

Comment: jagjordi - what about your power supply? Single or double?

Comment: Hi @LvW, its a Single power supply (5V from an usb plug) Thanks

Comment: Each (ideal) integrator has - per definition - a DC gain approaching infinity. Therefore, the opamp has no dc feedback. But this causes severe problems for the opamp to find a stable DC bias point within the linear operating range. Therefore, you must slightly "disturb" the integration function and place a (large) resistor in in parallel to the feedback capacitor  This transfers your circuit into a lowpass with a very low 3dB-frequency.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it has a relation, but check your inverting(-) and non-inveting(+) input connections in your PSpice schematics. You should connect them in the opposite way to obtain the non-inverting integrator layout.

Secondly, even if you fix your connections, you should check your r c values again and recalculate your gain. Lastly, I think your input signal should be peak-to-peak -V to +V, not 0 to +V. In your case of input signal, result of the integration should not be an exact triangle wave(if I'm not wrong).